How to migrate Kafka key property using dataflow flex template?
Can Dataflow flex template gs://dataflow-templates/2024-10-29-00_RC00/flex/Kafka_to_BigQuery_Flex migrate kafka "Key" property to BigQuery table, alongside the main message itself? According to the docs there is persistKafkaKey parameter but it doesn't work for me - the column _key (of type bytes) in BigQuery table is null for all rows (the columns for message fields are properly populated). Any idea what could be wrong? I ran the dataflow flex template like this:
gcloud dataflow flex-template run <NAME> \
  --template-file-gcs-location gs://dataflow-templates/2024-10-29-00_RC00/flex/Kafka_to_BigQuery_Flex \
  --additional-experiments=use_runner_v2 \
  --region europe-west1 \
  --service-account-email=<SA> \
  --network=<NETWORK> \
  --subnetwork=<SUBNETWORK> \
  --additional-experiments=use_network_tags=<NETWORK_TAG> \
  --additional-experiments=use_network_tags_for_flex_templates=<NETWORK_TAG> \
  --parameters '^&^readBootstrapServerAndTopic=<SERVERS>;<TOPIC>' \
  --parameters writeMode=SINGLE_TABLE_NAME,\
outputTableSpec=<PROJECT.DATASET.TABLE>,\
outputDeadletterTable=<PROJECT.DATASET2.TABLE2>,\
writeDisposition=WRITE_APPEND,\
persistKafkaKey=true,\
useBigQueryDLQ=true,\
messageFormat=JSON,\
kafkaReadAuthenticationMode=NONE,\
kafkaReadOffset=earliest


The command to run the template seems correct. I think, either the key is not populated and it's actually null in the source message, or there is an issue/bug with the template. If it's the latter, you'll probably have to create a support ticket with Google Cloud to investigate this specific Dataflow job.
